# How to change target platform on Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, visual-foxpro

I run into an error when trying to add a VisualFoxPro OLE DB provider to my SSIS project. When trying to click on data links I got the "**Class not registered**" error. When I press 'Test Connection' it returns

> Test Connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   The 'VFPOLEDB.1' provider is not registered on the local machine

After a few hours of googling I understood that I had to change the target platform of my project from 'AnyCPU' to (x86), however, when I go to
 **MySolution--> Properties --> build**  I can only see output path there is nowhere where I can set the the target platform. On top of the properties window there are three controls Configuration with the options Development and Active(Development), then platform with N/A and the last one, Configuration Manager.

I have no idea where to go from here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For debugging in VS - go to **Debugging** window and set **Run64BitRuntime** property to false. See screenshot below (from VS 2013 but shows the setting needed).
[image]